# How to access task (DFT) level variable in SSIS in case same name variable? I seem to be accessing package level variable in Conditional split

Tags: variables, ssis, scope, rowcount, dataflowtask

I have 2 varaibles name Row_Count 1st at package level and 2nd at task level and both have default value zero.

[image]

I have assigned variable value through Row Count Transformation

[image]

and checked it for condtion in conditional split.

[image]

It seems in Row Count Transformation tasklevel varaible got value assigned and in Conditional split it is reading from Pacakge level varibale. How can i make sure it reads from DFT level variable?

Comment: why do u have the same variable name for different scope ? It's generally a bad practise

Comment: @praveen pacakge with this 2 varibles is working for few years not sure why it was done like that. As i can not confirm "is pacakge level varaible is used?" if yes where so i do not wish to take chance by changing name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

Change the variable namespace for one the variables having the same name but different scope

[image]

Now while accessing the variable in Derived Component ,you can diffrentiate the variable name using their namespace like below

[image]

Comment: good idea. +1. I do not wish to make change to varaible namespace as that might break something else in package.